# Completely fill a TextBlock with repeating text

Tags: c#, wpf, textblock

I need to create a textblock that is completely filled with a repeating text.

The font size should change as well so approximately the same number of characters are displayed no matter the textblock size.

I have the following code:

```xml
<TextBlock
    Name="Watermark"
    Background="White"
    FontSize="14"
    Foreground="DarkGray"
    TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" />
```

And the related code-behind:

```cs
// Really bad function...
void GenerateWatermarks()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(watermarkString))
    {
        return;
    }
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        builder.Append(watermarkString);
    }

    Watermark.Text = builder.ToString();
}
```

Here is an example of what I would like to get :

[image: a busy cat]

The text is generated in large quantity to fit the whole textblock, but if a resize occurs, the text nor the font size evolve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try placing TextBlock into a Viewbox with Stretch set to `Fill` or `UniformToFill`

```
<Viewbox StretchDirection="Both" Stretch="Fill">
    <TextBlock
        Name="Watermark"
        Background="White"
        FontSize="14"
        Foreground="DarkGray"
        TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" 
        Width="480" Height="320"/>
</Viewbox>
```

[image]

Comment: This works, thanks. I just need one more thing: how do I create my repeated text the first time without my ugly function ?

Comment: @Valsov, it depends on your requirements. what exactly makes it ugly?

Comment: The fact that I cannot estimate the number of strings I need

Comment: "Watermark" textblock has fixed FontSize, Width and Height. I think, it is possible to approximate how many characters will fit, and calculate number of repeats based on watermark text